# What is the best way to sync your codefiles to your remote server?

Tags: version-control, synchronization

currently I am maintaining a django web application and I am using `rsync` via `ssh` to sync between my files and edits, using `www-data` user.

Then I `reload` the apache server.

I have tried git but had many problems on pushing, initiating a `bare` `git` couldn't help either.

Apart from deleted files from the source, rsync does it's job quite good.

What do you use?

Using OS: `Ubuntu 10.04 LTS x64` on both server and local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use mercurial, it's really easy to get running locally and very easy to push changes between different "servers".

you don't say what O/S you're using. I'm using Windows with tortoiseHg. I also use the VisualHg add-in for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to sync files between machines, I use `BitTorrent Sync`. Works on every major platform and it is super easy to configure. It even works for mobile devices.

Check out http://www.bittorrent.com/sync